# Insert page break in word when page has pictures that can be moved

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft

When I insert a picture the cursor remains in the top left corner. If I fill the page with only pictures no text and need a blank page at the end of the pictures to add more pictures, how do I do this with the cursor still at the top. Insert Black Page puts a blank page before the page with pictures because that is where the cursor is. Hitting enter only moves all the pictures to a new page again leaving a blank page before the page with pictures.

Answer (score 1):

### Go to the end of the document and press Ctrl+Enter

You can get to the end of the document using **Ctrl+End**.

Pictures inserted are either floating or in-line with text. If they are floating they will be anchored to a paragraph. With no text, this will be the first paragraph. Ctrl+End moves past everything.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but this did not work for me.

Comment: Janine, please do not expect volunteers assisting here to reconstruct your problem to try to solve it. Would you care to add a link to a sample document with the problem saved on DropBox or OneDrive?